# How to list the employees who have worked at the company for longer than the average

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting a blank table when running this query. How would I change this in order to list employees who have worked at the company for longer than the average

```
SELECT first_name, last_name 
FROM employees 
WHERE DATEDIFF(SYSDATE(), hire_date) > ALL (SELECT AVG(hire_date) FROM employees)
```

Comment: See what happens if you put a DATEDIFF in the subquery as well.

Answer (score 0):

As jarlh pointed out you need the average *duration* , i.e. DATEDIFF in your subquery as well:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name 
FROM employees 
WHERE DATEDIFF(SYSDATE(), hire_date) > 
        ALL (select avg(DATEDIFF(SYSDATE(), hire_date)))
```